# How do I use a "minimum" function in R given these two columns in a data frame?

Tags: r

Given the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(c("1990, 1991", "1997, 2004", "2005"), c("1991, 1999", "1994", "1995, 2011"))
```

I want to create a 3rd column to the right in the data frame, which pastes the lowest year in the row based on the two columns.

An element that for instance shows "1990, 1991" is supposed to indicate two different years that are to be looked at separately.

So in the first row, R will analyse the years:

1990, 1991, 1991 and 1999 and then write 1990 in the third column since it's the lowest out of them all.

The final table should look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(c("1990, 1991", "1997, 2004", "2005"), c("1991, 1999", "1994", "1995, 2011"), c("1990", "1994", "1995"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `apply` approach

```
df$result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) min(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(paste(x, collapse=", "), ", ")))))
```

Collapse the 2 columns into a single string using

```
paste(x, collapse=", ")
```

Split the resulting string into a vector

```
unlist(strsplit(..., ", "))
```

Find minimum number

```
min(as.numeric(...))
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if the 2 columns are part of a bigger data frame with multiple columns and I want to identify those two columns based on their names? (assuming their column names are "Years1" and "Years2"

Comment: You could subset with `apply(df[,c("Years1", "Years2")], ...)`

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `splitstackshape::cSplit` function along with `dplyr` as:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)

df$minval <- df %>% cSplit(c("one", "two")) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric) %>%
  mutate(minval = apply(., 1,min, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(minval)

df
#          one        two minval
# 1 1990, 1991 1991, 1999   1990
# 2 1997, 2004       1994   1994
# 3       2005 1995, 2011   1995
```

**Data:** I have changed sample data to provide column names. (which is not needed for solution but it helps in aesthetic look of answer)

```
df <- data.frame(one = c("1990, 1991", "1997, 2004", "2005"), 
               two = c("1991, 1999", "1994", "1995, 2011"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way by using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(x = c("1990, 1991", "1997, 2004", "2005"), 
           y = c("1991, 1999", "1994", "1995, 2011"))
df

#>           x          y
#>1 1990, 1991 1991, 1999
#>2 1997, 2004       1994
#>3       2005 1995, 2011

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(z = paste(x, y, sep = ",") %>% 
               str_split(",") %>% 
               combine() %>% 
               min())

#>Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#>Groups: <by row>

#>  # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>           x           y          z    
#>        <fct>       <fct>      <chr>
#>1  1990, 1991  1991, 1999       1990 
#>2  1997, 2004        1994       1994 
#>3        2005  1995, 2011       1995
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base option:

```
df$result <- sapply(strsplit(gsub(",","",do.call(paste,df))," "),min)

df
#          one        two result
# 1 1990, 1991 1991, 1999   1990
# 2 1997, 2004       1994   1994
# 3       2005 1995, 2011   1995
```

result is character here (`min` works with characters), wrap `as.numeric` around the `sapply` call if that's an issue.